# Is it possible to lock/focus the cursor to the last line of textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say we have a `textarea` in our html code.
This `textarea` contains some.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Cursor Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea class="text" cols="200" rows="40">
Some Random text.
More random text
> [fixed cursor position]
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to prevent to move the cursor from moving above or before the specified position? *(in the code marked as `[fixed cursor position]`)*
I want still be able to write, but I don't want to exceed the start position. (either above or before the starting position -> *`[fixed cursor position]`*)

So if the focus is on the `textarea` the cursor should move to its position, when typing. (onKeyPress, to still be able to select and mark text in the `textarea`)

In this case -> *(at least)* Line 3, Col 3

Can this be done in JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: save the lowest possible position of the cursor in a js var and then onfocus and onkeydown for that textarea you check where the cursor is and if the cursor is on a position < lowest possible position then set the cursor to the lowest possible position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little function which will help you:

```
jQuery.fn.lockCursor = function() {

    return this.each(function() { //return the function for each object

        if (this.setSelectionRange) { //check if function is available

            var len = $(this).val().length * 2; //avoid problems with carriage returns in text
            this.setSelectionRange(len, len);

        } else {

            $(this).val($(this).val()); //replace content with itself
            //Will automatically set the cursor to the end

       }

    });

};
$('.text').keypress(function(){
    $(this).lockCursor(); //execute function on keypress
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7u9b397L/)**

**Edit**

I updated my code, to make it possible to edit the text, which has been added by myself:

```
var selectEnd; //global variable
jQuery.fn.lockCursor = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length * 2;
        this.setSelectionRange(len, len);        
    });
};

$('.text').focus(function(){
    $(this).lockCursor();
    selectEnd = $(this).val().length; //save original length of value
});

$('.text').keypress(function(){
    if($(this)[0].selectionStart < selectEnd){ //cursor position is lower then initial position
        $(this).lockCursor();
    }
});
```

Explanation:

`$(this)[0].selectionStart` is necessary, because it must be only one element and not a set of elements provided by the jQuery-Object

Note: this solution may be not compatible to all browser and versions, depending on their support of the `selectionStart` -method

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nqdLu1oj/)**

**Reference**

[setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange)

Comment: It works well but with one problem.  If you type text, you can't edit it in the middle.  It always goes to the last position of the edittable text.  So if you type "helo", you have to delete the "o" to add the missing "l".